# I am looking for specific algorithms in Orange

Tags: python, algorithm, orange, c4.5

I am learning data mining in class and I am having trouble with the Orange library. 
I am coming from Weka to Orange and am trying to find the J4.8 and the C4.5 algorithms, but I can't find them listed.

A google search takes me to a page that says it has the algorithms (http://docs.orange.biolab.si/widgets/rst/classify/c45.html), but I still can't find them. 
I am using Python 2.7. Is it compatible or do I have to write them?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here - http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.classification.tree.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that C4.5 within Orange is no longer supported. You are advised to use the standard Orange tree learner/classifier.

If you want to use C4.5 in Orange you have to build the corresponding extension yourself. Follow these instructions: http://docs.orange.biolab.si/reference/rst/Orange.classification.tree.html#building-the-c4-5-plug-in